# VBA array code with composite key dictionary

Tags: arrays, vba, dictionary, key, composite

I trying to loop through large excel data into a dictionary and pull out.
Here is my code I'm trying
A lot of error an I'm getting stuck.
Please help me whit my code~!!

[image]

```
Sub Me()

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastrow = ws1.Range("B" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = ws1.Cells(Range("C2").Row, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1
    vd = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws1.Range("C3").Resize(1, LastCol - 1)))
    va = ws1.Range("b4").Resize(lastrow - 2, 1)
    For i = LBound(va) To UBound(va)
        dict.Add addToString(vd(1), va(i, 1)), ws1.Cells(i + 3, 3).Value

        Debug.Print dict("uniqueXXXuniqueYYY")
    Next i
       
End Sub


Public Function addToString(ParamArray myVar() As Variant) As String

    Dim cnt     As Long
    Dim val     As Variant
    Dim delim   As String: delim = "unique"

    For cnt = LBound(myVar) To UBound(myVar)
        addToString = addToString & delim & myVar(cnt)
    Next cnt

End Function
```

Comment: Excuse me, why is your addToString() function better than the built-in [Join()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function)? Or simple concatenation?

Comment: What errors and on which lines?

Comment: Since you've not included the row/column headers in your screenshot it's difficult to relate that to your code.  Also "A lot of error" is not a useful description of the precise errors you're getting.  Please include error text and the line(s) where they occur.